# haskell ghc complete hierarchical libraries overview

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is there a complete overview of the libraries that come bundled with GHC?
[This overview](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/) is incomplete. For example the [Text.Regex](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat-0.95.1/docs/Text-Regex.html) module is not listed.

If a module is not listed here does that mean that it's deprecated?
If not is there a reason why some modules are listed and others are not?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your own link points to hackage, which _is_ the most comprehensive repository of Haskell libs. http://hackage.haskell.org/ Also try https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ to search for functions/packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list you link actually contains the documentation for all the packages that are bundled with GHC. Notably GHC does not bundle `regex-compat` as you suggest.

The GHC Commentary contains a historic view of bundled packages: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Libraries/VersionHistory

Answer (score 2):

The overview page you link to refers to the "GHC bindist" which is just the compiler and a set of assorted packages. For instance, the bindist for 7.10.2 is located here:

https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_10_2

The "Haskell Platform" is a bindist + some more packages. On OS X you can find the docs for all of the Haskell Platform modules plus modules you have installed at a location like:

~/Library/Haskell/share/doc/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2/index.html

If a module is not listed it just means that it hasn't been installed.